# How to define a template function to set tolerations either from global or from local tolerations in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to check if `tolerations` is available in `global` then use that for all the pods (a parent chart with subcharts) and if each submodule/subchart has its own `tolerations` then use that instead of the global one. So this is how I defined it:

```
{{/* Set tolerations from global if available and if not set it from each module */}}
{{- define "helper.tolerations" }}
{{- if .globalTolerations.tolerations }}
tolerations:
  {{toYaml .globalTolerations.tolerations | indent 2}}
{{- else if (.localTolerations.tolerations) }}
tolerations:
  {{toYaml .localTolerations.tolerations | indent 2}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and in each sub-chart, I have this:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  my-container-name
      {{toYaml (include "helper.tolerations" (dict "globalTolerations" .Values.global "localTolerations" (index .Values "ui-log-collector"))) | indent 6}}
```

The default values in `values.yaml` are defined as below:

```
global:
  tolerations: []
ui-log-collector:
  image: a.b.c
  tolerations: []
some-other-sub-charts:
  image: x.y.z
  tolerations: []
```

Now when I want to deploy the stack using helm, I pass a `values.yaml` to override `tolerations` as below:

```
global:
  tolerations:
    - key: "key1"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "value1"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    - key: "key1"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "value1"
      effect: "NoExecute"
ui-log-collector:
  tolerations:
    - key: "key2"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "value2"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    - key: "key2"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "value2"
      effect: "NoExecute"
```

With this set up I currently get this error:

```
 error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 34: could not find expected ':'
```

I tried different things but I without `toYaml` I get:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.tolerations): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.tolerations: got "string", expected "array"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in the code as written.  Go templates produce text output, so you don't need to call `toYaml` on them.  Also, when you call `indent`, it doesn't know about the indentation of the current line, so if you're going to `indent` something the `{{ ... }}` template expression usually needs to be on an unindented line.

The call itself, for example, should look like:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  my-container-name
{{ include "helper.tolerations" (dict "globalTolerations" .Values.global "localTolerations" .Values.ui-log-collector) | indent 6}}
{{-/* at the first column; without toYaml */}}
```

Within the helper function, using `toYaml` is appropriate (`.Values` is a composite object and not a string) but the `indent` line again needs to begin at the first column.

```yaml
tolerations:
{{toYaml .globalTolerations.tolerations | indent 2}}
```

You may find it useful to use `helm template` to debug issues like this; it will write out the generated YAML file instead of sending it to the cluster.  The `toYaml` form in the question will probably convert the `tolerations:` block into a YAML string, and that would be pretty visible in the output.

Comment: Thanks. With this set up I get this error: `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.tolerations): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.tolerations: got "string", expected "array"`

Comment: Great worked! I just needed to add `not empty` to if statements: `if not (empty .globalTolerations.tolerations)` otherwise it returns `nil` as string. Thanks